# Upload data to SQLServer

Tags: vba, excel, adodb

I'm making a macro to upload data to SQLServer, I want this table and every time you run the macro

1. Want to work with Recordset Add The last added row

---

```
   Sub GetData()
       Call RecordsetFromSheet(prueba)
   End Sub
```

---

```
Public Function RecordsetFromSheet(ByVal tableName As String)
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim strCon As String
Dim strSQL, strInput As String
Dim cmd As Object
```

> Opening Connection to SQL Server

```
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.ConnectionString = OleDbConnectionString("xxxxx", "xxxx", "xx", "xxxxxxx")
cn.Open
```

---

> Closing Connection

```
If CBool(cn.State And adStateOpen) = True Then
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
End If
End Function
```

---

> Function To StringConnection

```
Function OleDbConnectionString(ByVal Server As String, ByVal Database As String, _
    ByVal UserName As String, ByVal Password As String) As String
    If UserName = "" Then
        OleDbConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=" & Server _
            & ";Initial Catalog=" & Database _
            & ";Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;"
    Else
        OleDbConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=" & Server _
            & ";Initial Catalog=" & Database _
            & ";User ID=" & UserName & ";Password=" & Password & ";"
    End If
End Function
```

---